# Angular Firebase update phone number

Tags: angular, firebase, firebase-authentication

I know there are a lot of questions out there about how to update the phone number of a firebase user.

However, is there a way to do it without doing the validations?

I want to change the phone number, even if the user can inform an invalid phone.

I'm not using it as authentication.

In my case, the authentication using phone number is actually disabled.

Here is what I tried already:

```
const { currentUser:fuser } = firebase.auth();
if(fuser && fuser.phoneNumber !== phone) {
    try {
        const verifier = new firebase.auth.RecaptchaVerifier('recaptcha-container', {
            callback: (response) => console.log('callback', response),
            size: 'invisible',
        });
        const phoneProvider = new firebase.auth.PhoneAuthProvider();
        const id = await phoneProvider.verifyPhoneNumber(phone, verifier);
        const code = window.prompt('Inform the received code:');
        const cred = firebase.auth.PhoneAuthProvider.credential(id, code);
        await fuser.updatePhoneNumber(cred);
    } catch(e) {
        console.error(e);
    }
}
```

It is returning an error saying the phone authentication is disabled on my account. So, that's the case, I just need to change the phone number as user information, not as an authentication option.

The error:

> FirebaseError: Firebase: The given sign-in provider is disabled for this Firebase project. Enable it in the Firebase console, under the sign-in method tab of the Auth section. (auth/operation-not-allowed).

Comment: Please edit the question to show what you tried that doesn't work the way you expect, including what you might have tried from other questions, along with any error messages.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think that option exists in the client-side SDKs. In the Admin SDKs there *is* an option to simply [set a phone number](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/admin/manage-users#update_a_user), but those are designed to run in trusted environments, such as your development machine, a server that you control, or tools like Cloud Functions/Cloud Run.

So what you could do is wrap the necessary code in Cloud Functions, then call that from your client-side application, and of course then secure that access.